# How to request RTVolume using IB py

Tags: python

I have a small Python program that I use with Interactive Brokers.  I would like to request time, price, and volume using RTVolume.  Here is a small snippet of my code.  Can anyone tell me how to include a request for RTVolume.

class BerryWrapper(EWrapper):

```
def __init__(self):

    pass

def tickPrice(self, tickerId, field, price, canAutoExecute):

    with open('log_me.txt','a') as file:

        if (field == 4):

            print 'Last[%s,%s,%s]' % (tickerId, price, canAutoExecute)

            file.write('Last[%s,%s,%s]' % (tickerId, price, canAutoExecute))

        elif (field == 1):

            print 'Bid[%s,%s,%s]' % (tickerId, price, canAutoExecute)

            file.write('Bid[%s,%s,%s]' % (tickerId, price, canAutoExecute))

        elif (field == 2):

            print 'Ask[%s,%s,%s]' % (tickerId, price, canAutoExecute)

            file.write('Ask[%s,%s,%s]' % (tickerId, price, canAutoExecute))


def tickString(self, tickerId, tickType, value):
    if (tickType == 45):
        tod = strftime("%H:%M:%S", localtime(float(value)))
        print('TickTime[%s, %s]' % (tickerId, tod))
        with open('log_me.txt','a') as file:
            file.write('TickTime[%s, %s]'+'\r\n' % (tickerId, tod))
```

Do I simply add?

```
def RTVolume(self, price, size, time, volume, VWAP, flag)
```

Answer (score 0):

To request RTVolume, you need to issue a request in the following format:

eClientSocket.reqMktData(reqId, contract, "233", snapshot)